# unable to hide an entire column using a fa icon in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I need a help with a issue in tabulator.
I have placed an fa icon to hide and particular column. The icon is placed in an header in table and on click of the icon the entire column should be hidden but i am unable to do so.

[image: The table in question]

Using headerClick function i an able to hide the column but i need to have the function on the icon click not on header click in tabulator.

this is the code which is working but we need to enable click on the Fa icon not on header click.

```
var showHideButtonFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){

    var btn = document.createElement("i");
    btn.classList.add("pull-right","fa","fa-eye-slash","btn");
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');

    var title = document.createElement("span");
    title.appendChild(btn);

    var textnode = document.createTextNode(formatterParams["titleName"]); 
    title.appendChild(textnode);
    title.style.css ="text-align:center"
    $(btn).on('click', function (e) {

    });

    return title;
}
```

```
//PriceBreakup Table --START

        var priceBreakupTablejsondata = [[${rfxForm.itemSupplierDetails}]];

        if(priceBreakupTablejsondata == "{}" || priceBreakupTablejsondata == null){
            priceBreakupTablejsondata = priceBreakupTablejsondata;
        }else{
            priceBreakupTablejsondata = JSON.parse(priceBreakupTablejsondata);
        }

        var columnsObjects =[]

         function showAllColumns(){
            columnsObjects.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
                value.show();
            });
        }

        var priceBreakupTable = new Tabulator("#priceBreakupTable", {
            height:310, 
            data:[],
            layout:"fitColumns",
            placeholder:"",
            columnVertAlign:"bottom",
            columns:[
                //{title:"#", field:"rownum ", widthGrow:1, formatter:"rownum"},
                {title:"Item", field:"item", widthGrow:2, headerSort:false},
                {title:"Quantity", field:"quantity", widthGrow:1, headerSort:false},
                {title:"UOM", field:"uom", align:"center", widthGrow:1, headerSort:false},

            ],

        });

        //column definition in the columns array

        if(priceBreakupTablejsondata!=null){
            for(i=0; i<Object.keys(priceBreakupTablejsondata).length; i++){

                var itemsArray = priceBreakupTablejsondata[i];
                var supplierArray = itemsArray.supplierList;

                for (var s = 0; s < supplierArray.length; s++) {

                    if (i==0) {
                         priceBreakupTable.addColumn(
                                { title:supplierArray[s].supplierName,align:"center", 
                                     headerClick:function(e, column){
                                        //e - the click event object
                                        //column - column component
                                         columnsObjects.push(column);
                                         column.hide();
                                    },
                                    titleFormatter:showHideButtonFormatter, titleFormatterParams:{"titleName":supplierArray[s].supplierName},
                                    columns:[
                                        {title:"Unit Rate", field:"unitRate_"+s, headerSort:false, align:"center", widthGrow:2},
                                        {title:"Tax Amount", field:"taxAmount_"+s, headerSort:false, align:"center", widthGrow:2},
                                        {title:"Total Amount", field:"totalAmount_"+s, headerSort:false, align:"center", widthGrow:2.2},
                                    ],
                                }
                                ,false);
                        }
                  }   
            }
        }

            function reformatData(itemJSON){
                var output = [];
                var totalSuppliers;
                var headersRow = {
                        item: "",
                        quantity: "",
                        uom: "",
                    }

                var itemsLength = Object.keys(itemJSON).length;
                for(i=0; i < itemsLength; i++){

                    var row = {
                        item:itemJSON[i].item,
                        quantity:itemJSON[i].quantity,
                        uom:itemJSON[i].uom,
                    }
                    var supplierArray = itemJSON[i].supplierList;

                    for(s=0; s < itemJSON[i].supplierList.length; s++){

                        totalSuppliers = itemJSON[i].supplierList.length
                        var supplierName = supplierArray[s].supplierName;
                         row["unitRate_"+s] = supplierArray[s].unitRate;
                         row["taxAmount_"+s] = supplierArray[s].taxAmount ;
                         row["totalAmount_"+s] = supplierArray[s].totalAmount ;

                    }
                        output.push(row);
                }

                for(hid=0; hid < totalSuppliers; hid++){
                    headersRow["unitRate_"+hid] = "Unit Rate";
                    headersRow["taxAmount_"+hid] = "Tax Amt.";
                    headersRow["totalAmount_"+hid] = "Total Amt.";          
                }
                //alert(JSON.stringify(headersRow));
                output.unshift(headersRow)
                return output;
            }


        if(priceBreakupTablejsondata!=null){
            priceBreakupTable.setData(reformatData(priceBreakupTablejsondata)); 
        }

        //PriceBreakup Table --END
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle working example link?

Answer (score 0):

The click event listener for your btn in your header formatter should be should be:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    cell.getColumn().hide();
});
```